# woocommerce_output_related_products_args hook not working as expected

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to show a specific product with id 64391 in related products section but the following code doesn't work for that. Am I missing something?

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args','msrp_reconfigure_related_products_args', 20 );

     public function msrp_reconfigure_related_products_args($args)
      {

        $args['posts_per_page'] = 5; 
        $args['columns'] = 5;
        $args['post__in'] = array(64391);

        return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can find [on the WC core source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_output_related_products.html#1867). The filter hook `woocommerce_output_related_products_args` triggers via `wc-template-functions.php` file and passes it's return to `woocommerce_related_products` function. So the `$args` parameter isn't the args used in db query and you can not use `post__in` key in it.

Instead, to add specific products to related products section, you can use `woocommerce_related_products` filter as below:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_related_products', 'add_related_products');
function add_related_products($related_product_ids)
{
    // WC source code stores IDs as string in this array, so I did that too
    $related_product_ids[] = '81';
    return $related_product_ids;
}
```

Tested and it's working.

**Note:** This filter hook has 3 parameters: `$related_posts`, `$product_id` and `$args`. You can limit these new products to only display on specific single product pages, by checking  `$product_id`

Comment: when is this filter called? I tried it on the single product page and it is not called